# Trouble with options in shiny timevis app

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am building a gantt chart using shiny + timevis.

- https://daattali.com/shiny/timevis-demo/
- https://github.com/daattali/timevis
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timevis/timevis.pdf

This package is closely intertwined with visjs/timeline and in the help you eventually get pointed here:

- http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/index.html#Configuration_Options

Most work, like turning off the stacking or setting start/end dates. I am having trouble applying two options:

- verticalScroll = TRUE does not work
- stackSubgroups = TRUE/FALSE does not seem to do anything relative to just the stack option

here is my server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)

source("sampleData.R")

function(input, output){

  output$appts <- renderTimevis(
    timevis(
     data = pt.clean, 
     groups = pt.group, 
      options = list(
        stack = FALSE, 
        stackSubgroups = TRUE, 
        orientation = "top",
        verticalScroll = TRUE,
        zoomKey = 'ctrlKey',
        start = "8/15/2017",
        end = "12/15/2017",
        max = "2019",
        min = "2016",
        margin = list(item = 10, axis = 10),
        minHeight = 750, 
        maxHeight = 750
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Hoping someone can point out if I am doing something wrong or confirm/offer any solutions. Not looking for anyone to write the code for me I am just a little stumped, this is my first venture into shiny/webapps using R. Bonus if anyone has any ideas on how to add subgroup labels under the group labels on the y axis...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timevis` package is currently using visjs version 4.16.1 (you can see that [here](https://github.com/daattali/timevis/tree/master/inst/htmlwidgets)) which is from Aug 30 2016.

Using a quick github search in the visjs github repo, I found that the vertical scroll feature was added [2 months ago](https://github.com/almende/vis/pull/3504) and the stack subgroup feature was added [in Dec 2016](https://github.com/almende/vis/pull/2519). That would explain why these features aren't working.

This means that updating to the current version of visjs should allow these features to be used. There sounds like a simple 5 minute task, but unfortunately it is not. There is currently [an open issue on github to update timevis](https://github.com/daattali/timevis/issues/32), and you're free to help with that if you have the time and expertise.